# Repeat a command line multiple times

Tags: repeated-commands

I want to turn

```
one two three four
```

into

```
'one' 'two' 'three' 'four'
```

(I have surround.vim)

I can do: `ysiW'`, then do `W.` repeatedly until I've surrounded all words in the line

But I would like to repeat the movement (`W`) and repetition (`.`) multiple times without needing to manually type that (imagine much longer lines).

I tried

```
:4norm ysiW'W
```

but of course that fails. I tried pressing `4` then typing `:norm ysiW'W`, but that only runs it once (after deleting the automatically inserted `.,.+3` range).

How do I do this without having to record a macro?

Comment: Does `:s/\w\+/'&'/g` solve your problem? If not, please give a more representative example.

Comment: @Quasímodo imagine the line `f g one two three four` and you want it `f g "one" "two" "th...`

Comment: @theonlygusti `:s/\w\{2,}/"&"/g` will only replace on words with at least two characters, so it won't match `f` or `g`.

Comment: @filbranden how about `f g f g f g` and you want `f g f "g" "f" "g"`. Yes you can continue making the substitution more complex, but I'd just love to learn about a way to repeat commands. Looks like it doesn't exist. (I guess you can `3@:`)

Answer (score 2):

With a macro:

```
0qqysiW'W
```

and then `3@q`.

---

The issue is that `:normal` with a range is line-wise; that is, it repeats the normal command on each line in the range.

You *could* do

```
normal ysiW'<C-r>=repeat('W.', 3)<CR>
```

But at that point you're doing more work than the original, I think.

---

Quasímodo points out in the comments that

```
substitute/\w\+/'&'/g
```

is a little more natural, and I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Using a macro or a `:s` command is probably the easiest way to get this task done...

But if you'd like to explore an alternative, then the [`gn`](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#gn) command is a good fit. This commands selects the next search match in a visual selection. You can use it as a text object, so you can have your `ys` command act on the `gn` block, which you can then simply repeat with a `.`, without the need for a motion to get to the next match.

The problem with using the `gn` command here is that we need a fairly complex regular expression, since it needs to only match the text *before* the modification, but not match it *after* it. If the search pattern still matches the text after the modification, the `gn` command will apply the modification again to the current block, rather than skip to the next one.

So let's come up with a search that will match sequences of non-whitespace characters, *as long as* they don't start with a single quote.

This search pattern should work:

```
/\v(^|\s@<=)[^' \t]\S+
```

If you have [`'hlsearch'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27hlsearch%27) set, you'll see Vim highlighting each of the individual words, `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`. If you surround any of them with `'`, it will stop being highlighted, which means it will no longer match.

This regex is fairly complex. I'm using ["verymagic" mode](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv) to avoid having to backquote many metacharacters. Then I'm matching a start of line `^` or a space, but I'm using a [zero-width match-behind `/\@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D) to match it without including it into the pattern. This is to ensure we only match beginning of words. Then I'm using `[^' \t]` to match a character other than the single quote, a space or a tab. So this is the start of a word (sequence of non-whitespace characters) that *doesn't* start with a single quote.

Having performed this search, we're ready to use the `gn` magic. Set your cursor somewhere in the first word you want to change, in this case `one`, and then use:

```
ysgn'
```

This will surround the `one` in single quotes: `'one'`. If you have `'hlsearch'` enabled, you'll see that `'one'` is no longer highlighted, since it's not a match anymore.

At this point, you can repeat the `ysgn'` command with a single `.`. Since the word under the cursor is not a match, Vim will jump forward to the next match and act on it, so you'll get `'one' 'two'`. Repeat it one more time with `.` and you'll get `'three'`, and finally one last `.` for `'four'`. Done!

So this is probably overkill for this specific case, but when you're doing operations that modify the term enough that it's easy to match it *before* the change and not match it *after* the change, this technique is super useful. One great example is switching identifiers from `snake_case` to `CamelCase` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Once again, I suggest to work with https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi

I would have clicked each word with the mouse then `<c-n>`
When all selected type `S'`
The S' surrounds it with apostrophe.

You can also select with keyboard, by doing `\\/\<` which searches beginnings of words. Type `<c-n>` until all are selected, then esc and `sw` (selects word) .